# Drupal 7 returning theme() to page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-themes

I am developing a module and I need to call different .tpl.php layouts from the theme directory per page.So what I currently have is:

```
 return theme('adverts_index', array('adverts' => $advertsThemeArray));
```

That is what I return in one of the page callback functions. Now this works perfectly without a problem but in another page callback function within the module I attempt the same thing with a different theme hook but it does not call the layout specified by the theme hook.

```
 $r = theme('adverts_view_advert', array(
      'advert' => array(
        'id' => $advert->aid,
        'seller' => $advertiser,
        'more_from_user' => array(),
        'year' => $advert->year,
        'condition' => $advert->condition,
        'region' => $advert->region,
        'city' => $advert->city,
        'content' => $advert->description,
        'bids' => $allBidsArray,
      ),
    )
  );
  return $r;
```

The page is not complete blank, the main page.tpl.php which is used on every page which contains the header and what not does still display. Just the template I am trying to call  to its contents is not displaying.

This is my hook_theme:

```
 function adverts_theme() {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['adverts_index'] = array(
      'template' => 'adverts-index',
      'variables' => array(
          'advert' => array(
            'title' => null,
            'formatted_price' => null,
            'image' => null,
            'permalink' => null,
            'formatted_date' => null,
            'description' => null,
          ),
        ),
    );

  $theme['adverts_view_advert'] = array(
      'template' => 'adverts-single',
      'variables' => array(
          'advert' => array(
                'id' => null,
                'seller' => null,
                'more_from_user' => null,
                'year' => null,
                'condition' => null,
                'region' => null,
                'city' => null,
                'content' => null,
                'bids' => null,
            ),
          ),
        );
  return $theme;

}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`arguments` changed to `variables` in Drupal 7, and since either `variables` or `render element` is required the registry won't be picking up your theme.

Make the two changes in the `hook_theme()` implementation, clear the caches, and you should be good to go.

Comment: What's in your adverts-single.tpl.php file?

Comment: Static html page to test, normally it has a bunch of variables which need to be filled in but its not even calling the page so..